# Can we upload a logo with a lot of unnecessary points?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, tools

When I use the shape builder tool in Illustrator to combine 2 clean shapes, it produces a lot of points and when i try to remove the un necessary points I feel like it's not as clean as before ..is it right to upload a logo this way?

Sorry, I'm kind of new to illustrator and it's my first Qustion here, i made an example to clear it up ..
[image]
[image] 
In The first photo, there are what i meant by The un necessary points, i mean it's still one circle?
and when i tried to remove the points, it gives me the result in the 2nd photo, So is it right to remove all of them, then use the direct selection tool to redraw a clean circle Or nothing wrong with leaving all these points just produced after using the shape builder tool?
(can't upload more photos)
thanks

Comment: Please make an [edit] with images so we can get a better understanding what your question is.

Comment: Upload where? For what purpose? In what format? Of course you _can_ upload any file, no matter how many vector points it contains.

Answer (score 1):

A good practise while creating vector logos or icons is to keep them with the lowest amount of points.

In order to avoid the creation of so many points while merging shapes I would suggest to try different methods of combining shapes.

Try using the Shape Merger tool (Shift + M on AI's latest release) or by using the pathfinder tool (Window > Pathfinder).

Also, make sure you expand your shapes (Object > Expand) before merging anything. Make a backup of your shape/logo before doing this step.

Answer (score 0):

> can we upload a logo with a lot of un necessary points?

What do you mean by unnecessary?

If the logo is a finished logo then there might be no reason but without seeing an image it's going to be hard to answer your question.  Personally if you have a lot of unnecessary points and know it you should clean it up.  Clean points make it easier to edit over time if you need to.  After spending several years in the print field I have more respect for someone that delivers me a file with fewer, un-needed points, then someone that delivers a file that appears to be scanned.  Have you tested these points because if this is a small logo you designed and if someone plans to blow this thing up you should ask yourself will the unnecessary points be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I don't think putting the logo without any meaning make sense at all. Logo is the identity of the company. So I would say Logo might describe you and your company. Make it a worthy only.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree, I just made this Example above to clear my Question.